# Ruby on Rails. Organizing common partials in subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm Rails beginner.

As i know, i should place my common partials in `app/views/application` like  `app/views/application/_validation_errors.html.erb`. In that case i can use `render 'validation_errors'` everywhere in my views and Rails will find right partial.

But i want to organize my particles in subfolders. For example, i want to place the file like `app/views/application/messages/_validation_errors.html.erb` and render it like  `render 'messages/validation_errors'`, but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to do something like that? Or maybe somebody can advise how to act.

Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your folder structure correctly, you have an application folder, then a messages subfolder? If so, try: `render 'application/messages/validation_errors'`

Comment: It works, but if i place partial in application folder, i can do `render 'validation_errors'` and Rails will look for a partial in current folder at first (For example i have article_controller and file `app/views/article/edit.html.erb`. `render 'validation_errors'` looks in `app/views/article` and if it doesnt exists goes to the application folder)
And if i place partial in subfolder of application, the mechanism discribed above doesnt work.
I want `render 'messages/validation_errors'` try to find partial in current folder (`views/article/edit`) and if its not exists in application folder

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'm not sure how to achieve this. My understanding is that if you only put the partial's name, it'll look in the current folder, otherwise you have to explicitly tell it to look in a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding…

> I want render 'messages/validation_errors' try to find partial in current folder (views/article/edit) and if its not exists in application folder

… this might do the trick:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :_append_view_path

  def _append_view_path
    ["app/views/#{controller_path}", 'app/views/application'].uniq.each do |extra_path|
      append_view_path(extra_path)
    end
  end
end
```